# How to modify a model property from a background periodic task?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, properties, javafx-8

I'd like to update an application that manages several buildings. Each of these wears the number of persons it contains. Every 10 seconds, the population of each building grows by 1.

What I mean by "update" is "port from Swing to JavaFX".

The current Swing application implements the periodical action with a background `javax.swing.Timer` thread:

```
new Timer(10000, (e) -> {
   for (Building building : theSuperKawaiBuildingList) {
      building.setPopulation(building.getPopulation() + 1);
   }
});
```

... and `model.Building` is a sub-class of `java.util.Observable`:

```
public class Building extends Observable {
   private int population;

   public synchronized int getPoulation() {
      return population;
   }

   public synchronized void setPoulation(int value) {
      population = value;

      setChanged();
      notifyObservers();
   }

   public Building(int initPopulation) {
      population = initPopulation;
   }
}
```

Now, I'd like to use JavaFX instead of Swing and the binding capabilities of the API to build a new GUI, possibly implementing the `model.Building` class like so:

```
public class Building {
   // <editor-fold desc="FX Property - Population">
   private final IntegerProperty population;
   public IntegerProperty populationProperty() { return population; }
   public int getPopulation() { return population.get(); }
   public void setPopulation(int value) { population.set(value); }
   // </editor-fold>

   public Building(int initPopulation) {
      population = new SimpleIntegerProperty(initPopulation);
   }
}
```

I guess a `java.util.Timer` can fit the bill when it comes to the periodical stuff, but after some readings, I have doubts about the (thread) safety of updating a property that would be bound to an active scene graph from a background task...

Unless the binding comes with some magic that makes what I want to do possible, what's the best practice to do that.

Comment: Context PS: I'm a JavaFX beginner, this would be my first app with this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update a property in the model from a background thread if it is bound by a property of a UI component in the scene graph.

You can wrap the call that updates the model in `Platform.runLater(...)`, so that it executes on the FX Application Thread:

```
new Timer(10000, (e) -> {
   Platform.runLater(() -> {
       for (Building building : theSuperKawaiBuildingList) {
           building.setPopulation(building.getPopulation() + 1);
       }
   });
});
```

(or do the equivalent with a `java.util.Timer`).

Another approach (probably better) is to use the JavaFX Animation API:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), e -> {
   for (Building building : theSuperKawaiBuildingList) {
      building.setPopulation(building.getPopulation() + 1);
   }
});
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

Any handlers on the key frames that are part of the timeline are executed on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: Ok, so it's not considered as "evil" to implement a background task with the animation API? Also, I guess I won't need those `synchronized` anymore...

Comment: BTW, if the property wasn't bound to the GUI, I could update the property without worrying about all of that right? Like, this constraint only comes from the GUI mono-thread design.

Comment: No, it's probably the preferred approach, *as long as* the thing you are doing periodically is not in of itself time consuming (which is the case with the example you posted). If you are doing something time-consuming on a regular basis, and want to update the UI at the end of each time-consuming task, then use a [`ScheduledService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).

Comment: @Odepax Yes, that's correct. You can modify properties on any single thread: but you can only modify the state of the UI on the FX Application Thread. Any listeners registered with a property (which is how a binding is implemented) will be invoked on the same thread that the property is changed, so if your listeners (bindings) modify the UI, the property needs to be changed on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: @Odepax Also note " to implement a background task with the animation API" is not quite a technically correct description of what's happening here. The animation works simply by registering itself with the FX Application Thread. On each "pulse", each animation is checked to see if it has to be updated, and updates are called. So the animation approach does not create any new threads (it really just registers "triggers" with the existing UI thread). The timer approach creates a whole new thread that does nothing other than schedule code to run on an existing thread, which is less efficient.

Comment: Just to make it clear: if I use a `ScheduledService`, I'll still have to update a bound property from a `Platform.runLater()`call. So it's just about delegating hard work to another thread but the property update will still have to occur on the JFX Application thread?

Comment: @Odepax Not explicitly: if you use a `ScheduledService`, you can use its `setOnSucceeded(...)` handler, which is invoked *on the FX Application Thread* every time a task scheduled by the service completes normally.

Comment: Given that most of the model properties will be bound to the UI, is it a bad practice to make a call to `Platform.invokeLater()` from the setters?